# Addressing paint issue with new aluminum windows

Tags: aluminum, window-frame

I just had brand new high-end aluminum windows installed. Black ones, very nice. Supposedly the very high-end stuff.

After the installation, a different contractor did the framing finish around with gyproc and drywall compound. There were some sanding and some dust got on the windows, obviously.

Before painting, we tried to gently clean up the dust on the aluminum window frame. As the picture below shows, we now get to see the bare aluminum as if the black paint somehow disappear or was scratch by... the gyproc dust?

What I'm wondering:

- Is this expected ?
- Should the usual drywall dust and light maintenance be sufficient to strip away the paint over the window ?
- If this was enough to get the paint away, how can I expect to obtain the advertised 40 years lifetime on the side exposed to wind, sun and rain ?
- Is this rather an indication of a fabrication issue ?

The white electric cover plate is just there for sizing. The red rectangle show the part on the right side of the opening window were the bare aluminum is showing. The white part is not just drywall dust, it doesn't come off with a wet cloth.

At this point I'm mostly considering next steps: Consider it a fabrication defect, or consider it damage from the drywall job. I'll eventually get to consider ... a paint fix?

[image]

Comment: the 40 year warranty is probably not for paint

Comment: Perhaps it got accidentally sanded too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on there.

I don't see a primer.

A like possibility is that they just powder coated it, or more like still, just spray painted it with no primer. This could result in thin paint in certain areas like cracks.

Your only option is to touch up.

Comment: Most likely was properly primed and painted but contractor sanded it by mistake while doing the wall. But, glad to confirm "Your only option is to touch up."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, drywall product dust is abrasive. Dependent on the concentration of dust, it could be like 400grit sandpaper.
The bare aluminum needs to be primed with a 100% acrylic primer like Zinsser 1-2-3 primer available at any of the big box stores like Lowe's or Home Depot.